# Change oval shaped button background programmatically

Tags: android, button, oval

> I want to change `Button` background color programmatically the button
>   shape(oval). I have changed in xml.

**This is the code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>  
        <solid android:color="#f9f9f9"/>  
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFF4917" /> 
            </shape>
```

I am using `Button.backgroundColor(COLOR.RED)` to change this `Button` but problem is that it's changing button color, but it is making my button rectangular shape(default shape of a button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify it using this simple method down below

```
GradientDrawable BackgroundShape = (GradientDrawable)btn.getBackground();
BackgroundShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Happy coding :) Btw I edited your questions, You have made spelling mistakes in your original.

Answer (score 0):

Use it. It will make your rectangular shap to oval shap when click on button.

**style_login_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorDeepOrange"/>
            <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorOrange"/>
            <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorOrange"/>
            <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And apply to `Button` . Like -

```
<Button
               android:id="@+id/btnSignin"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/text_btn_login"
               android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
               android:textSize="25dp"
               android:padding="30dp"
               android:textAllCaps="false"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
               android:background="@drawable/style_login_button"/>
```

Comment: He wants to set the button to oval programmatically using code.